Is Every Homotopy Equivalence Class Associated With A Skeleton?
Is there an example of spaces $X$ and $Z$ which are homotopy equivalent, but there is no $Y$ which embeds via homotopy equivalence into both, $X$ and $Z$? And vice versa, are there spaces which embed via homotopy equivalence into all spaces to which they are homotopy equivalent, like the point or $S^1$?

You already answered the second question?

Ah, I'm not sure about it! It was more like a follow up question, are the point or $S^1$ of that property?

Well the point clearly has this property. Also more generally discrete spaces. Including the empty space.

I see! And what about the $S^n$?

I don't know the answer to the second question (aside from the trivial example of a discrete space), but here is a negative answer to the first question: The 'pinched torus' $X=(S^1\times S^1)/(\ast\times S^1)$ is homotopy-equivalent to $Z=S^1\vee S^2$. Now, if $Y\hookrightarrow Z$ is a subspace inclusion and a homotopy equivalence, it has to be surjective and thus the identity. Indeed, if $Y$ were to miss some point of $Z$, its inclusion factors (up to homotopy) through $S^1\hookrightarrow S^1\vee S^2$ or $S^2\hookrightarrow S^1\vee S^2$, hence wouldn't be surjective on $\pi_2$ or $\pi_1$ respectively. Thus, $Y=Z$, but this space does not embed into $X$ since $S^2$ does not embed into $X$.
If $S^2\hookrightarrow X$ were an embedding that misses the 'pinched point', it would be an embedding $S^2\hookrightarrow S^1\times(0,1)$, which has to be a homeomorphism by invariance of domain, but the spaces aren't even homotopy-equivalent. If $S^2\hookrightarrow X$ were an embedding that hits the 'pinched point', say as image of $p\in S^2$, then invariance of domain still implies that $S^2-p\hookrightarrow S^1\times(0,1)\subseteq X$ is an open embedding. Thus, the image of the embedding is the union of an open subset of $S^1\times(0,1)$ and the 'pinched point'. This image is closed since $S^2$ is compact, so altogether the open image of $S^2-p$ in $S^1\times(0,1)$ has to be closed, contradicting that these spaces are not homeomorphic.
